# Cannot apply constraints in storyboard

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode8, xcode9.2

I am trying to apply constraints to my views for my app in Xmarin.iOS in the interface builder. But i cannot apply them fully in 4 directions hence it looks misplaced. I tried to do it avaible constraints but no luck . I am attaching screen shots. This is what i have

[image]

but this is what i need

[image]

I am using Visual studio 15.5.2, Xamarin 4.8.0.753 , Xamarin.iOS 11.6.1.2  and Xcode 9.2 in High Sierra.

Comment: Try to unload project and reload it.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT tried it. no luck

Comment: Which control is it?  Which parent view do you place it inside?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT it's a simple UIVIew inside a UIViewController and this is not just for a single control the entire storyboard behaves like this.

Comment: It seems the position constraints are unavailable , try to create a new storyboard or xib  file to see if problem still exists.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT creating a new did the trick Thanks .Can i get all my views from old storyboard .?

Comment: Copy the viewcontrollers(views) and paste....